# File not exist Solc error when trying to import data feed into my contract

Tags: visual-studio-code, blockchain, solidity, chainlink, brownie

[image]

[image]

[image]

I have tried changing different versions of solc, solidity, and chainlink contracts but it doesn't work.

Error:

```
contracts/Lottery.sol:4:1: ParserError: Source "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.6/interfaces/AggregatorV3Interface.sol" not found: File outside of allowed directories.
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.6/interfaces/AggregatorV3Interface.sol";
```

Comment: What params are you passing to the `solc` command? It seems like you're only allowing some directories to import contracts from, but `node_modules` is not among them.

Comment: I started compiling my contract with command "brownie compile".

Comment: I have attached my code and yaml file as well.

Comment: I have adjusted the question title and fixed the display of your 3rd image. Better insert code as text instead of using images.

Comment: It seems that you haven't saved `brownie-config.yaml` file before run. This big white dot in VSCode. Add source code rather than print screens

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the yaml file being in the tests folder is the problem. I would move that file to live in your top level directory.